# How to test the Model has has_secure_password?

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Lets say I have User model as below..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

I would like to test whether `User` has `has_secure_password` but not sure how to do it. And I *don't* want to test [what rails has been tested](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/test/cases/secure_password_test.rb).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What I have been doing is just checking if the object responds to authenticate and has the password_digest field.

```
test "user model has secure password" do 
  assert_respond_to @user, :password_digest
  assert_respond_to @user, :authenticate, "User requires has_secure_password"
end
```